# My prefix is weird, My suffix is a friend (v1)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix is weird.
- My suffix is a friend.
- My infix is a creature to be feared.
- My whole has a massive extend*.

*Clarification (not needed, but may clear something up):

> The verb 'extend' is being used as a noun here in order to fit the rhyme scheme. There isn't much more to it than that.

Check out [another version of this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101775/my-prefix-is-weird-my-suffix-is-a-friend-v2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Globally

My prefix is weird.

> [Glob](https://adventuretime.fandom.com/wiki/Grob_Gob_Glob_Grod)

My suffix is a friend.

> Ally

My infix is a creature to be feared.

> [Loba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_She-Wolf_(1965_film))

My whole has a massive extend*.

> A worldwide extent

Comment: Wow this is a really good answer, can't believe it fits so well ! It's not the answer I'm looking for, but no credit taken away from you :) I'm going to accept this as an answer and post a follow-up question.