# My prefix is Weird, My suffix is a Friend (v2)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This is the same question as [My prefix is weird, My suffix is a friend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101769/my-prefix-is-weird-my-suffix-is-a-friend), but with a couple of ever-so-slight modifications (and obviously a different answer):

- My prefix is Weird.
- My suffix is a Friend.
- My infix is a creature to be feared.
- My whole has a massive extend*.

*Clarification (not needed, but may clear something up):

> The verb 'extend' is being used as a noun here in order to fit the rhyme scheme. There isn't much more to it than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Albatross**

The subtle difference is:

> Capitalization, for proper nouns (names)

Prefix Weird

> Weird **Al** the parody singer

Suffix Friend

> **Ross** from the TV show *Friends*

Infix creature

> **bat**. Aaaahhhhhh

Final clue and answer

> **Albatross** is a giant bird, and metaphor for large anxiety or hardship that can feel massive and extend into other areas of ones life

Comment: Nice !! More importantly albatrosses have massive wingspans (the largest of any bird) :)

Comment: Thanks! The prefix hit me, then I started going through the suffix characters until the word hit me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is quite right, but I'll post it anyway:

> megalomaniacally

My prefix is Weird.

> megalo - **abnormally** large or great

My suffix is a Friend.

> ally - an ally could be considered someone **friendly** to you

My infix is a creature to be feared.

> maniac - I don't know if it would be considered a creature, but they are often **feared**

My whole has a massive extend*.

> this word is very long - 16 letters!

Comment: Not quite. The subtle difference between this question and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101769/my-prefix-is-weird-my-suffix-is-a-friend-v1 is a clue.